# How to make the window resize automatically?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am tried to see different sources that speak about dynamic resize of the window but nothing is really working with me. I tried the following code but as you will see in the figures below more than half of the window is empty when maximizing the window.

```
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title('Optimization Sphere')
root.resizable(True, True)
```

[image][image]

Comment: What geometry manager are you using? If you are using `.grid` then look at `.columnconfigure` and `.rowconfigure`. It also wouldn't be a bad idea to look at the `sticky` parameter when calling `.grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using `grid` exclusively, or at least for the layout of the highest level of widgets.

With `grid`, rows and columns will expand or shrink to fit their contents as best they can. If there is extra space, that extra space will go unused.

You can configure `grid` to allocate space to one or more rows and one or more columns. As a rule of thumb when using `grid`, you should always do this for at least one row and at least one column. Typically that is the column with the largest widget -- a text widget, a canvas, a tree, something like that.

You control this by giving a row or column 'weight'. The weight tells `grid` what to do with extra space. The values are relative, so if you have one column with a weight of 1 and one with a weight of 3, the one with the weight of 3 will get three out of every four extra pixels.

In your case I'm guessing you want to give all extra space to column 1, which you would do like this:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Without seeing your actual code it's impossible to know if that's the exact right thing to do. However, the point remains that if you're using `grid`, you need to give a non-zero weight to at least one column if you want that column to expand to fill empty space.